# Number conversion in Pyhton

Tags: python, binary, hex, decimal, calculator

I am making a calculator and I want to add the feature of number conversion but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I'm aiming for: when i click the BIN button (or any of the number conversion buttons) it types it out, then I type the binary number, I click any other number conv. button for example DEC and it types it out and when I press the equal button it should give me the binary number in decimal, but it doesn't. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import simpledialog, messagebox
import tkinter.messagebox
import math

current_input = ""
current_number_system = None
conversion_type = None
root = Tk()
root.geometry("650x400+300+300")
root.title("Scientific Calculator")
switch = None

# Button on press
#Branje datoteke
def dat_clicked():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Text Files', '*.txt')])
    
    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            content = file.read().replace('\n', '')
            disp.delete(0, END)  # Clear previous content
   
            pos = len(disp.get())
            disp.insert(pos, content)

def handle_number_conversion(number_system):
    global conversion_type
    conversion_type = number_system
    # Update the display or perform any necessary actions

def handle_number_click(number):
    global current_input
    current_input += str(number)
    # Update the display or perform any necessary actions

def handle_logical_gate(gate_type):
    global current_input
    current_input += f" {gate_type} "
    # Update the display or perform any necessary actions
    disp.delete(0, END)
    disp.insert(END, current_input)

    if current_number_system == "BIN":
        # Check for logical gate operations
        if "AND" in current_input:
            operands = current_input.split("AND")
            result = bin(int(operands[0], 2) & int(operands[1], 2))[2:]
            print(f"{operands[0]} AND {operands[1]} = {result}")
            # Update the display or perform any necessary actions
        elif "NAND" in current_input:
            operands = current_input.split("NAND")
            result = bin(~(int(operands[0], 2) & int(operands[1], 2)) & 0xFFFFFFFF)[2:]
            print(f"{operands[0]} NAND {operands[1]} = {result}")
            # Update the display or perform any necessary actions
        elif "OR" in current_input:
            operands = current_input.split("OR")
            result = bin(int(operands[0], 2) | int(operands[1], 2))[2:]
            print(f"{operands[0]} OR {operands[1]} = {result}")
            # Update the display or perform any necessary actions
        elif "NOR" in current_input:
            operands = current_input.split("NOR")
            result = bin(~(int(operands[0], 2) | int(operands[1], 2)) & 0xFFFFFFFF)[2:]
            print(f"{operands[0]} NOR {operands[1]} = {result}")
            # Update the display or perform any necessary actions
        elif "XOR" in current_input:
            operands = current_input.split("XOR")
            result = bin(int(operands[0], 2) ^ int(operands[1], 2))[2:]
            print(f"{operands[0]} XOR {operands[1]} = {result}")
            # Update the display or perform any necessary actions
        elif "XNOR" in current_input:
            operands = current_input.split("XNOR")
            result = bin(~(int(operands[0], 2) ^ int(operands[1], 2)) & 0xFFFFFFFF)[2:]
            print(f"{operands[0]} XNOR {operands[1]} = {result}")
            # Update the display or perform any necessary actions
        else:
            # Handle other cases (e.g., no logical gate, simple binary operation)
            pass

def perform_logical_gate_operation(operands, operation):
    if operation == "AND":
        return bin(int(operands[0], 2) & int(operands[1], 2))[2:]
    elif operation == "NAND":
        return bin(~(int(operands[0], 2) & int(operands[1], 2)) & 0xFFFFFFFF)[2:]
    elif operation == "OR":
        return bin(int(operands[0], 2) | int(operands[1], 2))[2:]
    elif operation == "NOR":
        return bin(~(int(operands[0], 2) | int(operands[1], 2)) & 0xFFFFFFFF)[2:]
    elif operation == "XOR":
        return bin(int(operands[0], 2) ^ int(operands[1], 2))[2:]
    elif operation == "XNOR":
        return bin(~(int(operands[0], 2) ^ int(operands[1], 2)) & 0xFFFFFFFF)[2:]
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown logical operation: {operation}")

def handle_equal_click():
    global conversion_type
    global current_input, current_number_system
    try:
        expression = current_input.strip()

        # Check if the expression contains a conversion command
        if "DEC" in expression and ("BIN" in expression or "OCT" in expression or "HEX" in expression):
            # Split the expression into three parts: first_base, number, second_base
            parts = expression.split()
            if len(parts) == 3:
                first_base, num, second_base = parts
                result = convert_to_target_base(num, second_base)
                print(f"{num} {first_base} {second_base} = {result}")
                # Update the display or perform any necessary actions
            else:
                raise ValueError("Invalid input format")
        else:
            # Handle other cases (e.g., no conversion command)
            if current_number_system == "BIN":
                # Check for logical gate operations
                logical_operations = ["AND", "NAND", "OR", "NOR", "XOR", "XNOR"]
                for operation in logical_operations:
                    if operation in expression:
                        operands = expression.split(operation)
                        result = perform_logical_gate_operation(operands, operation)
                        print(f"{operands[0]} {operation} {operands[1]} = {result}")
                        # Update the display or perform any necessary actions
                        break
                else:
                    # Handle other cases (e.g., no logical gate, simple binary operation)
                    decimal_value = eval(expression)
                    result = {"DEC": decimal_value, "BIN": bin(decimal_value)[2:], "OCT": oct(decimal_value)[2:], "HEX": hex(decimal_value)[2:].upper()}
            else:
                # Handle non-binary number systems
                decimal_result = eval(expression)
                result = {"DEC": decimal_result, "BIN": bin(decimal_result)[2:], "OCT": oct(decimal_result)[2:], "HEX": hex(decimal_result)[2:].upper()}

        # Display the result in all number systems
        disp.delete(0, END)
        disp.insert(0, f"DEC: {result['DEC']}  BIN: {result['BIN']}  OCT: {result['OCT']}  HEX: {result['HEX']}")
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Value Error", f"Check your input: {str(e)}")


def btn1_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '1')
def btn2_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '2')
def btn3_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '3')
def btn4_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '4')
def btn5_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '5')
def btn6_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '6')
def btn7_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '7')
def btn8_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '8')
def btn9_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '9')
def btn0_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '0')

def key_event(*args):
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)

def btnp_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '+')
def btnm_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '-')
def btnml_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '*')
def btnd_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '/')

def btnc_clicked(*args):
    disp.delete(0, END)
    disp.insert(0, '0')

def btn_clicked(value):
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, value)
def conv_btn_clicked(value):
    global conversion_type
    conversion_type = value
    disp.insert(END, " " + conversion_type + " ")

def calculate_result():
    global conversion_type
    try:
        expression = disp.get()
        if conversion_type:
            conversion_result = convert_to_target_base(expression, conversion_type)
            disp.delete(0, END)
            disp.insert(0, str(conversion_result))
            conversion_type = None  # Reset conversion_type after use
        else:
            result = eval(expression)
            disp.delete(0, END)
            disp.insert(0, str(result))
    except Exception as e:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", f"Check your input: {str(e)}")

def convert_to_target_base(value, target_base):
    global conversion_type
    # Split the expression into three parts: first_base, number, second_base
    parts = value.split()
    if len(parts) != 3:
        raise ValueError("Invalid input format")
    
    source_base, num, target_base = parts

    # Split the expression into num and source_base using the last space as a delimiter
    last_space_index = value.rfind(' ')
    if last_space_index == -1:
        raise ValueError("Invalid input format")

    num = value[:last_space_index]
    source_base = value[last_space_index+1:]

    allowed_bases = {"BIN": 2, "OCT": 8, "HEX": 16, "DEC": 10}

    if source_base not in allowed_bases or target_base not in allowed_bases:
        raise ValueError("Invalid input format")

    decimal_value = int(num, allowed_bases[source_base])

    if target_base == "BIN":
        result = bin(decimal_value)[2:]
    elif target_base == "OCT":
        result = oct(decimal_value)[2:]
    elif target_base == "HEX":
        result = hex(decimal_value)[2:].upper()
    else:
        result = str(decimal_value)

    return f"{result}"


def dec_btn_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, ' DEC ')
def bin_btn_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, ' BIN ')

def oct_btn_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, ' OCT ')

def hex_btn_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, ' HEX ')
def tan_clicked():
    try:
        ans = float(disp.get())
        if switch is True:
            ans = math.tan(math.radians(ans))
        else:
            ans = math.tan(ans)
            disp.delete(0, END)
            disp.insert(0, str(ans))
    except Exception:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", "Check your values and operators")
def arcsin_clicked():
    try:
        ans = float(disp.get())
        if switch is True:
            ans = math.degrees(math.asin(ans))
        else:
            ans = math.asin(ans)
            disp.delete(0, END)
            disp.insert(0, str(ans))
    except Exception:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", "Check your values and operators")
def arccos_clicked():
    try:
        ans = float(disp.get())
        if switch is True:
            ans = math.degrees(math.acos(ans))
        else:
            ans = math.acos(ans)
            disp.delete(0, END)
            disp.insert(0, str(ans))
    except Exception:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", "Check your values and operators")
def arctan_clicked():
    try:
        ans = float(disp.get())
        if switch is True:
            ans = math.degrees(math.atan(ans))
        else:
            ans = math.atan(ans)
            disp.delete(0, END)
            disp.insert(0, str(ans))
    except Exception:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", "Check your values and operators")
def pow_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '**')
def round_clicked():
    try:
        ans = float(disp.get())
        ans = round(ans)
        disp.delete(0, END)
        disp.insert(0, str(ans))
    except Exception:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", "Check your values and operators")
def logarithm_clicked():
    try:
        ans = float(disp.get())
        ans = math.log10(ans)
        disp.delete(0, END)
        disp.insert(0, str(ans))
    except Exception:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", "Check your values and operators")
def sqr_clicked():
    try:
        ans = float(disp.get())
        ans = math.sqrt(ans)
        disp.delete(0, END)
        disp.insert(0, str(ans))
    except Exception:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", "Check your values and operators")
def dot_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '.')
def e_clicked():
    if disp.get() == '0':
        disp.delete(0, END)
        pos = len(disp.get())
        disp.insert(pos, str(math.e))
def bl_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, '(')
def br_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    disp.insert(pos, ')')
def del_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())
    display = str(disp.get())
    if display == '':
        disp.insert(0, '0')
    elif display == ' ':
        disp.insert(0, '0')
    elif display == '0':
        pass
    else:
        disp.delete(0, END)
        disp.insert(0, display[0:pos-1])
def ln_clicked():
    try:
        ans = float(disp.get())
        ans = math.log(ans)
        disp.delete(0, END)
        disp.insert(0, str(ans))
    except Exception:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", "Check your values and operators")
def mod_clicked():
    pos = len(disp.get())


# Label
data = StringVar()
disp = Entry(root, font="Verdana 20", fg="black", bg="mistyrose", bd=4, justify=RIGHT, insertbackground="#abbab1", cursor="arrow")
#disp.bind("<Return>", btneq_clicked)
#disp.bind("<Escape>", btnc_clicked)
#disp.bind("<Key-1>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-2>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-3>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-4>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-5>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-6>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-7>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-8>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-9>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-0>", key_event)
#disp.bind("<Key-.>", key_event)
#disp.insert(0, '0')
#disp.focus_set()
disp.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
# Row 1 Buttons
btnrow1 = Frame(root, bg="#000000")
btnrow1.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
dec_btn = Button(btnrow1, text="DEC", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=dec_btn_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
dec_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

bin_btn = Button(btnrow1, text="BIN", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=bin_btn_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
bin_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

oct_btn = Button(btnrow1, text="OCT", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=oct_btn_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
oct_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

hex_btn = Button(btnrow1, text="HEX", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=hex_btn_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
hex_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

mod_btn = Button(btnrow1, text="%", font="Segoe 21", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=mod_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
mod_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn1 = Button(btnrow1, text="1", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn1_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn2 = Button(btnrow1, text="2", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn2_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn3 = Button(btnrow1, text="3", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn3_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn3.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btnp = Button(btnrow1, text="+", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btnp_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btnp.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
# Row 2 Buttons
btnrow2 = Frame(root)
btnrow2.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
not_btn = Button(btnrow2, text="NOT", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=lambda: handle_logical_gate("NOT"), fg="white", bg="#333333")
not_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

and_btn = Button(btnrow2, text="AND", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=lambda: handle_logical_gate("AND"), fg="white", bg="#333333")
and_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

nand_btn = Button(btnrow2, text="NAND", font="Segoe 16", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=lambda: handle_logical_gate("NAND"), fg="white", bg="#333333")
nand_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)


bl_btn = Button(btnrow2, text=" ( ", font="Segoe 21", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=bl_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
bl_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
br_btn = Button(btnrow2, text=" ) ", font="Segoe 21", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=br_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
br_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn4 = Button(btnrow2, text="4", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn4_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn4.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn5 = Button(btnrow2, text="5", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn5_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn5.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn6 = Button(btnrow2, text="6", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn6_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn6.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btnm = Button(btnrow2, text="-", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btnm_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btnm.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
# Row 3 Buttons
btnrow3 = Frame(root)
btnrow3.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
or_btn = Button(btnrow3, text="OR", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=lambda: handle_logical_gate("OR"), fg="white", bg="#333333")
or_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

nor_btn = Button(btnrow3, text="NOR", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=lambda: handle_logical_gate("NOR"), fg="white", bg="#333333")
nor_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

xor_btn = Button(btnrow3, text="XOR", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=lambda: handle_logical_gate("XOR"), fg="white", bg="#333333")
xor_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

sqr_btn = Button(btnrow3, text=" √x ", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=sqr_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
sqr_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
pow_btn = Button(btnrow3, text="x^y", font="Segoe 17", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=pow_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
pow_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn7 = Button(btnrow3, text="7", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn7_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn7.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn8 = Button(btnrow3, text="8", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn8_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn8.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn9 = Button(btnrow3, text="9", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn9_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn9.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btnml = Button(btnrow3, text="*", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btnml_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btnml.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
# Row 4 Buttons
btnrow4 = Frame(root)
btnrow4.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
dat_btn_4 = Button(btnrow4, text="dat", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=dat_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
dat_btn_4.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
sinh_btn = Button(btnrow4, text="sin−1", font="Segoe 11 bold", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=arcsin_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
sinh_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
xnor_btn = Button(btnrow4, text="XNOR", font="Segoe 18", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=lambda: handle_logical_gate("XNOR"), fg="white", bg="#333333")
xnor_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
dot_btn = Button(btnrow4, text=" • ", font="Segoe 21", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=dot_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
dot_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btnc = Button(btnrow4, text="C", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btnc_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btnc.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
del_btn = Button(btnrow4, text="⌫", font="Segoe 20", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=del_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
del_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btn0 = Button(btnrow4, text="0", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btn0_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btn0.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btneq = Button(btnrow4, text="=", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=handle_equal_click, fg="white", bg="#FA8072")
btneq.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
btnd = Button(btnrow4, text="/", font="Segoe 23", relief=GROOVE, bd=0, command=btnd_clicked, fg="white", bg="#333333")
btnd.pack(side=LEFT, expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Keeps giving me error: invalid syntax (, line 0).
I want it to print out for example 'BIN 111 DEC' and give me the decimal number for 111.

Comment: Are you familiar with the format specifiers as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)? Also (just an aside) you should look at data-driven coding techniques. That would make your code more robust and **much** more concise

Comment: I got a "NameError: name 'conversion_type' is not defined" in the "btneq_clicked" function in the "if conversion_type:" line. This means that the global variable "conversion_type" does not yet have a value at the time it is used.  Also, you can split your expression: `first_base, number, second_base = disp.get().split()`

Comment: I tried everything but it still doesn't work, I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: This error is in the line "decimal_result = eval(expression)" in the function "handle_equal_click". The expression here is "expression = current_input.strip()". current_input is an empty string. eval("") throws a syntax error. Lots of code here, not sure how to use this variable (current_input). I assume current_input should be the content of the entry, so I tried changing the expression to "expression = disp.get().strip()".  I tried to convert "BIN 111 DEC". String goes to "result = convert_to_target_base(num, second_base)" and raise ValueError("Invalid input format") in this function.

Comment: Thit is because the value(num="111") that passed to function "convert_to_target_base" function does not need to be split again ("parts = value.split()").  This "convert_to_target_base" function is also used in "def calculate_result". In this function, you pass the entire expression to the "convert_to_target_base" function. So you have a function that receives value in two forms. If you plan to use "calculate_result", which is not used anywhere, you need to handle different data formats.

Comment: Also temporarily add a traceback to your try-except blocks to see what the error is and where it occurs.  import traceback and after "except Exception as e: " print(traceback.format_exc()).

Answer (score 0):

You have a VERY long Python snippet with a ton of methods and calls, and a high level error that doesn't relate to the code. I recommend creating a separate python file and slowly adding your code to it, running it each time you add something, to make sure you are not getting errors. Eventually you should have something where you can evaluate the logic of the problem, or you will see where the error is that is blocking you from getting your code to work.